# Using GetOptions to define a parameter that errors out when specified and input is missing but doesn't error out if parameter not specified at all?

Tags: perl

How do we define a CLI argument that errors out if we don't give an input but doesn't error out if we don't use that parameter at all?

Example : I invoke a program by:

```
perl program.pl --param1 input1
```

This should be an error:

```
perl program.pl --param1
```

But this should continue executing:

```
perl program.pl
```

Without giving `--param1` should continue executing. Defining `param1=s` or `param1:s` in GetOptions don't differentiate between giving `--param1` without input and not giving it at all ('=' case lets param1 be undef and ':' initializes to default value in both cases).

Answer (score 1):

The requested behaviour is provided by `=s`.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use v5.14;
use Getopt::Long;

GetOptions( "param1=s" => \my $param1 )
   or die "Usage\n";

say $param1 // "[undef]";
```

```
$ ./a.pl
[undef]

$ ./a.pl --param1 foo
foo

$ ./a.pl --param1
Option o requires an argument
Usage
```